# CompareValidator visibility

Tags: c#, comparevalidator

I'm having a problem with compareValidator on C#.
I have 2 errors that can show when I am validating password:
- the new password and the password cannot be the same, or 
- the new password fields must be the same

I used two comparevalidators. One to verify the current password and the new password field(the first only). And other to check if the new password field is equal to the confirm new password field.
So, the problem is when I enter the current password field equal to the new password field and I enter the confirm new password field different from the new password field, because both errors show up. I need to display one error at a time...

Is there a way to this only with compareValidator? Is there a way to get the "visibility" generated by the comparevalidator?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why asp-classic? maybe asp.net?

Comment: can you post your code, where you use the compareValidators. So we can provide a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

A custom validator is probably the way to go. See http://forums.asp.net/t/1566657.aspx for a similar question and an example of client and server-side validation functions, and the markup.